# Family of projections in a Banach space.

Tags: banach-spaces, nets, strong-convergence

Assume that we have a Banach space $X$ and a family of projections $\{P_\alpha\}_{\alpha}$ onto a finite dimensional subspaces $X_\alpha$. Let $\{e_{i,\alpha}\}_{i\in\{1,\dots,\dim X_\alpha\}}$ be a basis of $X_\alpha$.

Assume moreover that:

- $\sup_\alpha \|P_\alpha\|,\sup_\alpha \dim X_\alpha<\infty$
- $span \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ is dense in $X$
- $\{e_{i,\alpha}\}_{i,\alpha}$ is an (algebraic) basis of $span \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$

Does it follow that:

1) $(\sum_{\alpha\in F}P_\alpha)_F$, where $F$ are finite subsets of the index set, converge to identity operator in the strong topology as $F$ grows?

2) $\forall x\in X\; (\forall\, \alpha \;P_\alpha x=0 \Rightarrow x=0)$

1) obviously implies 2). I suppose neither of these is true, but i can't think of any counterexample.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second condition. Every finite-dimensional normed vector space is closed, so together with $X_{\alpha}$ being dense in $X$ this implies $X_{\alpha} = X$.

Comment: I suppose the second condition is to be interpreted as $\operatorname{span} \bigcup_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}$ is dense? In that case, indeed neither is true, we can find a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X_{\alpha}$ be the subspace spanned by $(\cos\alpha,\sin \alpha)$ for $\alpha \in [\pi/4,\pi/2]$ and $P_{\alpha}$ the projection onto $X_{\alpha}$ with kernel $\mathbb{R}\cdot (1,0)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the right interpretation of the second condition. I've also rephrased third condition, sorry about that. 
Thank You for Your example, i see that neither 1) nor 2) works here. What if we additionally assume that $P_\beta(\sum_{\alpha,i}C_{\alpha,i}e_{\alpha,i})=\sum_{i}C_{\beta,i}e_{\beta,i}$?